# Reverse a string without use of library function in java

Tags: java

I am new to programming I need to reverse a string without using the library function.

I am able to reverse but as expected.

```java
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
String s = br.readLine();
String rev = "";
ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
ArrayList<String> splitResult = new ArrayList<String>();

for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++)
    if (s.charAt(i) == ' ')
        list.add(i);
list.add(0, 0);
list.add(list.size(), s.length());
String[] words = new String[list.size()];

for (int j = 0; j <= words.length - 2; j++)
    splitResult.add(s.substring(list.get(j), list.get(j + 1)).trim());

System.out.println(splitResult);
String[] str = new String[splitResult.size()];
str = splitResult.toArray(str);

for (int i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
    if (i == str.length - 1) {
        rev = str[i] + rev;
    } else {
        rev = " " + str[i] + rev;
    }
}

System.out.println(rev);
```

Expected:
Input: i am coder
output: redoc ma i

actual
input: i am coder
output: coder am i

Comment: Your problem is that you're splitting it into words rather than treating the whole thing as one word.

Comment: Consider how you can iterate through the string as if it were an array of characters, from the end to the beginning.  As you do so, construct a new string from each character.

Comment: Are you allowed to call methods of class `String`? If yes, you may want to use `toCharArray()`, iterate over that and put every `char` to the beginning of another `String`.

Comment: `String reversed = new StringBuilder("I am a coder").reverse();`

Answer (score 2):

You can just provide an empty result variable, iterate the characters of the given `String` by using an enhanced `for`-loop (also known as `for`-each loop) setting every character to index 0 of the result variable by just concatenating the character to the result variable like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // input
    String s = "I am coder";
    // result variable for reverse input
    String reverseS = "";

    // go through every single character of the input
    for (char c : s.toCharArray()) {
        // and concatenate it and the result variable
        reverseS = c + reverseS;
    }

    // then print the result
    System.out.println(reverseS);

}
```

You can of course do that in a slightly different way using a classic `for`-loop and the length of the input, see this example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String s = "I am coder";

    String reverseS = "";

    for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
        reverseS = s.charAt(i) + reverseS;
    }

    System.out.println(reverseS);

}
```

Comment: Spent some time on this, but it was worth it!

Answer (score 1):

```
    String s = "I am coder";
    String rev="";
    for (int i = s.length()-1; i >=0; i--) {
        rev+=s.charAt(i);
    }
    System.out.println(rev);
```

I have set the index I to the last character of the given string and the condition is set to 0(i.e the first character). Hence the loop runs from the last character to the first character. It extracts each of the characters to a given new String. Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

You can just take another list go from last to first and display like this

```
BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        String s=br.readLine();

        ArrayList<Character> working = new ArrayList<Character>();
        ArrayList<Character> finished = new ArrayList<Character>();

        for (char ch: s.toCharArray()) {
            working.add(ch);
}
        for(int i = working.size() - 1 ; i>=0 ; i--){
            finished.add(working.get(i));
        }

        for(int j = 0 ; j < finished.size() ; j++){
        System.out.print(finished.get(j));
        }
```